# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Adding Lookup Value?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm developing a windows forms application & I've retrieved all the values from the look up by using the following code:

```
var value = item.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("attributename").Name;
```

Now comes the major task of assigning a value to the Lookup fields. When I tried to add the value it fails. I browsed in the internet and there is not much info about this. I could only find some **Xrm.Page** which is for web applications.

Can anyone of the experts please help on this & shred some light upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new entity object, set the attribute values you want (in this case an `EntityReference`) and then finally call `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Update`.

1. **Create a new entity object**

   ```
   var entity = new Entity { Id = new Guid("recordId"), LogicalName = "entityName" };
   ```
2. **Set attribute values**

   ```
   entity["attributeName"] = new EntityReference(new Guid("recordId"), "entityName");
   ```
3. **Call update**

   ```
   service.Update(entity);
   ```